# Elementary functions in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Looking for a way to get elementary functions and their derivatives I approach it like this:

```
abstract class Fun() {
    /** 
     * i = 0 -- the function itself, 
     * i = 1, 2, 3, ... -- its successive derivatives
     */
    abstract fun d(i: Int, x: Float): Float
}

class Lin(val k: Float) : Fun() { 
    // y = k*x
    override fun d(i: Int, x: Float, p: Float) = when (i) {
        0 -> k * x
        1 -> k
        else -> 0.0f
    }
}

class Sum(val fun0: Fun, val fun1: Fun) : Fun() {
    // y = fun0(x) + fun1(x)
    override fun d(i: Int, x: Float, p: Float) = fun0.d(i, x) + fun1.d(i, x)
}

class Example(val fun1: Fun, val fun2: Fun){
    var res = fun1.d(0, 5.25f) // fun1 value at 5.25f
    res = fun1.d(1, 3.29f) // fun1 first derivative at  3.29f
    val sum = Sum(fun1, fun2) // sum of f1 and f2
    res = sum(0, 3.78f) // sum value at 3.78f
    res = sum(1, 5.69f) // sum first derivative at 5.69f
}
```

Is there a more idiomatic way to do it in Kotlin?

I have exposed the problem as I had done in Java, that is, classes that contain functions. My question is if I can do the same with functions, pass them on to a class like:

```
class ParametricCurveXYZ(val fun_x: Fun, val fun_y: Fun, val fun_z: Fun) {

    fun pointToXYZ(s: Float) = VectorXYZ(fun_x.d(0, s), fun_y.d(0, s),    fun_z.d(0, s))

    fun tangent(s: Float) = VectorXYZ(fun_x.d(1, s), fun_y.d(1, s), fun_z.d(1, s)).normalized()

}
```

Comment: could you please provide a reference to an example of the pattern you want? In some other programming language maybe

Comment: I edited my question @voddan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use lambdas instead of regular classes and overload operators to combine lambdas.

```
fun lin(k: Float) = { i: Int, x: Float ->
  when (i) {
    0 -> k * x
    1 -> k
    else -> 0.0f
  }
}

operator fun ((Int, Float) -> Float).plus(that: (Int, Float) -> Float) =
    { i: Int, x: Float -> this(i, x) + that(i, x) }

fun doSomething() {
  val sum = lin(1f) + lin(2f)
  val res = sum(0, 3.78f)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It is what he wanted.